# How to remove %20 and %40 from cookies obtained from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I am pulling a cookie for display, but the cookie displays a %20 and a %40. how can this be removed within my jquery or html/css?

```
function readCookie(FullName) {
   var name = FullName + "=";
   var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
   for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
     var c = ca[i];
     while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
     if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
   }
   return "";
}
```

HTML:

```
<label id="first">Cookie result: <input id="name2" maxlength="25" name="namefield" readonly="readonly" size="20" type="hidden" /> </label>
<script>
$("#first").append(document.getElementById('name2').value = readCookie('FullName') + "!");
</script>
```

Comment: The title is misleading. These cookies are not obtained from nor via jQuery this is pure JavaScript. There's probably libraries (like e.g., https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) you can use to do this whole work for you as well.

Comment: do you know if there is a way using javascript to remove the %20 and %40 from the obtained cookie?

Comment: how did said cookie get said values in the first place? that should give you a clue as to how you should remove them.

Comment: Its from login information

Comment: I figured it out, I added .replace(/%20/g, ' ') to the end of readCookie('FullName')

Answer (score 0):

I added .replace(/%20/g, ' ') to the end of readCookie('FullName'). it removed the %20

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
decodeURIComponent(document.cookie)
```

More details can be found in the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent